# C# Importing .CSV Data Into MySQL Table Only Copies 1 Column

Tags: c#, mysql, .net, csv

I have a method written in C# that is attempting to copy the data in a .CSV file into a MySQL table that looks like this;

```
     public void writeToMySQL()
     {
        string constr = ConfigurationManager.ConnectionStrings["sqlString"].ConnectionString;
        using (MySqlConnection sqlCon = new MySqlConnection(constr))
        {
            try
            {
                sqlCon.Open();
                MySqlCommand sqlCmd = new MySqlCommand("LOAD DATA INFILE 'test.csv' INTO TABLE sdcdbftest.importexport;", sqlCon);
                sqlCmd.ExecuteNonQuery();
            }
            catch (MySqlException)
            {
                throw;
            }
        }
    }
```

What is happening however is that only the data from the first column of the .CSV file is copied over, nothing else. The .CSV file looks like so;

[image]

Finally this is how the table is structured on the Database through phpMyAdmin;

[image]

Is there any obvious reason as to why only the first column (cs_id) is being copied over?

Comment: @DavidG Works perfect thanks. Please feel free to post as an answer and I'll accept.

Comment: How does you raw csv file look like (as in a text editor, not in Excel)? Does that format comply with the default parameters of load data infile, such as field and line separators?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

From [the documentation](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.1/en/load-data.html), The default column terminator for the `LOAD DATA INFILE...` command is the tab (`\t`) character. So you need to specify you are using commas in the command like this:

```
LOAD DATA INFILE 'test.csv' 
    INTO TABLE sdcdbftest.importexport 
    FIELDS TERMINATED BY ',';
```

Comment: As an extension to this, is there a way I can specify specific columns to import whilst ignoring others? For example I just attemped to import only csid and t1_field however the data from t1_field was imported in the table column.

Comment: @Cbreeze Import into a temp table, then copy over the needed fields? It'd be easier than manually parsing the CSV data yourself

Comment: You can specify the column list like this `LOAD DATA INFILE 'test.csv' INTO TABLE sdcdbftest.importexport (csid, @dummy, @dummy2, t1_field, @dummy3);`, note the dummy values that cause those to be ignored.

Comment: @user3791372 How could I do this? Through 3rd party software?